# Sum of series $\sum_1 \frac{\cos(x)^{n-1}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm asked to find when this series converges and the sum of this series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)^{n-1}}{n!}$

I found out, with the ratio criteria that it converges everywhere but when $x=0+k\pi$ but I have no idea how to find the sum of this series.

Comment: It also converges at $x=0+k\pi$. You can verify directly.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
e^{\cos(x)}=1+ \cos(x) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{n-1}(x)}{n!} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I think you mean everywhere but $x=\pi/2 + k\pi$

Comment: @saulspatz Also there is convergence. In fact, the series converges *everywhere* on the real line: it is just a particular case of the well known series for the exponential function $\;e^x\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, the limits of summation aren't given.  I assumed OP was taking the lower limit of summation to be $n=0$ and worrying about where $\cos x = 0.$  Otherwise, the series obviously converges everywhere on $\mathbb R,$ and I couldn't imagine what the problem was.

Comment: Sorry @saulspatz, fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

$\mid \cos x \mid \le 1,$ so the series converges absolutely everywhere on $\mathbb R$ by comparison with the series $\sum{\frac{1}{n!}}=e.$

Answer (score 2):

If $x=2k\pi $ the series becomes $$\sum \frac {1}{n!} $$ which converges 
by ratio test and the sum is $e $

If $x=(2k+1)\pi$, it becomes
$\sum \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n!} $ which converges by alternate criteria and the sum is $e^{-1} $.

Comment: So it converges everywhere? @saulspatz says that it doesn't converge in $x=\pi/2+k\pi$...

Comment: @KatherineEnilin No, that was a misunderstanding.  After your clarification, I agree it converges absolutely on $\mathbb R$.